# Select/unselect option of a multiselect selectbox without pressing control key and changing the style

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I have a multi select select box here in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/bthucos7/1/) drawn as,

```
<select id="select" multiple>
    <option value="-1">Select</option>
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
    <option value="4">d</option>
</select>
```

How can I select multiple values without pressing `Ctrl` key. ie, when I select an option, if it's not selected already should be selected and vice versa.

**EDIT:**
 1. Also how can I style that multi select dropdown such that it can be displayed as similar as a single select dropdown.
2. I tried using the above [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641729/how-to-avoid-the-need-for-ctrl-click-in-a-multi-select-box-using-javascript) and sample is here: http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/ua057y5t/. But in this case I cant able to fire the change event then.

Comment: Might require JS, but this post discusses it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641729/how-to-avoid-the-need-for-ctrl-click-in-a-multi-select-box-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You are probably searching for smething like this, check discusion: [jquery select and unselect multiple input without ctrl click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085886/jquery-select-and-unselect-multiple-input-without-ctrl-click)

Answer (score 1):

Check this JQuery plugin :- " [Multi select avoiding ctrl button](http://nerdstuckathome.wordpress.com/2012/08/10/multi-select-avoiding-ctrl-button/) "

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. For multi-select without holding CTRL(Windows)/CMD(Mac), [try this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543862/selecting-multiple-from-an-html-select-element-without-using-ctrl-key#27056015).
2. For styling, you might be looking for:

   ```
   -webkit-appearance: none;/* Safari, Chrome */
   -moz-appearance: none;/* Firefox */
   ```

but then you need to style it yourself, background-color, font-size, etc.